# Using dd to cause an error in memory

Tags: dd

The command `dd if=/dev/mem of=/dev/null seek=16k bs=4k count=1` is used to test erroect injection for [edac](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/edac.txt). Why? As far as I know, dd is simply copying data from those devices to somewhere else. What bad can happen to cause an error to memory by copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You skipped the important part **before** the dd command, from the [kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/edac.txt):

> For example, the following code will generate an error for any write
>   access at socket 0, on any DIMM/address on channel 2:
>
> ```
>  echo 2 >/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/inject_addrmatch/channel
>  echo 2 >/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/inject_type
>  echo 64 >/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/inject_eccmask
>  echo 3 >/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/inject_section
>  echo 1 >/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/inject_enable
>  dd if=/dev/mem of=/dev/null seek=16k bs=4k count=1 >& /dev/null
> ```

The kernel driver generate errors, this has nothing to do with dd, dd is just used to trigger it.

Comment: So how does dd trigger a memory error exactly? I understand the inject things are for the configuration of error injection registers: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.42/drivers/edac/i7core_edac.c#L963 . The values the inject interfaces will be `anded` with each other and write to a register. But I don't understand how using dd can trigger error in memory.

Comment: @Amumu any read operation will trigger the error, this has **NOTHING** to do with dd, you could either use `dd`, `cat`, any other tool or just wait until it would read from that specific channel.

Comment: I see. Thanks. In the document (the Nehalem part), it mentions about using address match for error injection . What does it do? Does it mean, by using address match, it will cause an error at that specific physical memory address that is specified in address match register? And if edac hardware is working, when that faulty memory address is read, it should correct the error. Is that right?

Comment: @Amumu It depends, there are 5 different methods to match an address, like channel, dimm etc. And yes the error should be fixed.